# Foreach array to display the value in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, loops, pdf

I'm trying to create a PDF where the data are taken from the database. Here is how I do the variable declaration in my TypeScript.

```
essay = {
    "title": "",
    "author": { "fullname": "" },
    "intro": "",
    "conclusion": "",
    "paragraphs": [ { "paragraph": "" } ]
}
```

As you can see here, the paragraphs are in type of array. So when a button to generate the PDF is triggered, the function below will be called.

```
CreatePdf(){
    var docDefinition = {
      content: [
        { text: this.essay.title, style: 'header' },
        { text: new Date().toTimeString(), alignment: 'right' },

        { text: 'Written By : '+this.essay.author.fullname, style: 'subheader' },

        { text: this.essay.intro, style: 'story', margin: [0, 20, 0, 20] },

        // Foreach essay.paragraphs and display the value

        { text: this.essay.conclusion, style: 'story', margin: [0, 20, 0, 20] }
      ]
    }
    this.pdfObj = pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition);
    this.pdfObj.download();
}
```

The question is, how am I going to do the foreach to display all the paragraphs value in the `content:[]`? I'm trying to apply the following loop inside the content but can't do.

```
for(let parag of this.essay.paragraphs){
  console.log(parag.paragraph);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `...` operator and `map()`:

```
CreatePdf(){
    var docDefinition = {
      content: [
        { text: this.essay.title, style: 'header' },
        { text: new Date().toTimeString(), alignment: 'right' },

        { text: 'Written By : '+this.essay.author.fullname, style: 'subheader' },

        { text: this.essay.intro, style: 'story', margin: [0, 20, 0, 20] },

        ...this.essasy.paragraphs.map( p => {
            return {text: p.paragraph, style: 'story', margin: [0, 20, 0, 20]};
        }),

        { text: this.essay.conclusion, style: 'story', margin: [0, 20, 0, 20] }

      ]
    }
    this.pdfObj = pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition);
    this.pdfObj.download();
}
```

`map()` as the name suggests maps every element using the function given to it and `...` simply flattens an array.

Comment: Working like charm! Thank you :)